# How to find CPU temperature on any android with adb command

Tags: android, shell, adb

Ill am trying to find a way to get the temperature of the CPU of any android device only with adb command.

Comment: I'm developing an answer to this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246774/how-do-i-get-the-temperature-of-my-phone-via-adb/246775

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `adb shell ls sys/class/thermal/` to get list of thermal zones and then:

```
adb shell cat sys/class/thermal/[name of thermal zone]/temp
```

For example: `adb shell cat sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`

**Note:** Some of the thermal zones may return some weird values especially those with higher number. Also, some thermal zones return values in millidegree Celsius.

Comment: what are the units of the value returned? nvm, found doc (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt), updated answer above.

Comment: I got this `cooling_device3: Permission denied`
`thermal_zone0: Permission denied`
`thermal_zone1: Permission denied`

Comment: @Qamar It seems that you need su privilege to run this command. In case your device is not rooted, it may not be possible to get the temperature.

Answer (score 12):

**Note:** This is to find the temperature of the battery, however, not the CPU, so this doesn't actually answer the question but most people actually just want to find the temperature of their Android phone. So it will not be deleted until a new question arrives.

adb command:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery
```

This command dumps info from the Android battery manager.

output:

```
Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: true
  USB powered: false
  Wireless powered: false
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: false
  level: 3
  scale: 100
  voltage:4146
  temperature: 281
  technology: Li-ion
```

battery temperature: 28.1℃ (281/10)

Comment: is it possible to add some explanation of your answer, as well as the adb command and the sample output you've provided?

Comment: That command dumps info from the Android battery manager. The battery's temperature is displayed in 10ths of a degree Celsius, so the above is 28.1C. This is the temperature of the *battery* however, not the *CPU*, so this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: An observation, the parameters supported by "adb shell dumpsys battery" vary by device. For example, of the dozens of different device models I have for testing, only a few actually support the "temp" parameter.